# How to grep string and assign it to a variable in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file with the below details;

#### file name: allappsclus

```
cont:i-02dd208bf1d81c254
rs:i-0098ad0b59b7fe7cf
```

I want to use the value for  `i-XXX"=` in associated `cont` name and assign it to another variable.

If run my code and get an output it is

```
test-1.1.0.0
1insideif-CNS
```

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $jupyter    = 0;
my $controller = 0;
my $rstudio    = 0;
my $zeppelin   = 0;

my $fh= '/tmp/allappsclus';

open my $fh2, '<', $fh  or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";

while ( <$fh2> ) {

    if ( $_ =~ /jup/ ) {
        $jupyter = 1;
    }
    elsif ( $_ =~ /con/ ) {
        $controller = 1;
    }
    elsif ( $_ =~ /rs/ ) {
        $rstudio = 1;
    }
    elsif ( $_ =~ /zep/ ) {
        $zeppelin = 1;
    }
}

print "test-$rs.$con.$jup.$zep\n";

if ( $zepeq '0' && $jup eq '0' && $con eq '1' && $rs eq '1' ) {
    print "insideif-CNS";
}
else {
    print "do nothing";
}

close $fh;
close $fh2;
```

Now I want to print the value `i-02dd208bf1d81c254` instead of `CNS` in the output.

Comment: This question is missing a lot of details like what you mean by i-XXX, cont etc. Please provide more information, add details about what you've tried and it didn't work.

Comment: By writing code.

Comment: I have file and trying to get the value after ":" in associated "cont"  variable.

Comment: offhand I can think of about 10 methods of doing this with perl. I can also tell you for a fact that a single search on google will bring up pages full of results on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myStr = "cont:i-02dd208bf1d81c254 rs:i-0098ad0b59b7fe7cf";

if ($myStr =~ /cont:([^ ]+)/) # match the full pattern with the value you required
{
   $controller=1;
   $cont = $1;    # assign required value to a variable
}
print $cont;      # print the variable
```

This might work for you.

Comment: thanks ,it's working if i will use separate perl file but  i want to add to my existing  code to replace CNS to  "i-02dd208bf1d81c254"  in output. can you please help me how to achive this? And also the file is getting runtime so each run the values will change(which is in after "cont" value i.e. "i -02dd208bf1d81c254")